# how do I get UITableView to respond to viewDidRotate?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a UIViewController that inherits from UITableViewContoller:

```
@interface AllProductsViewController : UITableViewController
```

And I need to redraw my table cells if the device has been rotated.  Looks like I do not have access to viewDidRotate in a UITableViewController so what is the best approach to take in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The UITableViewController inherits from UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), so YES, you have access to those methods.